# JQuery load() function reloading the page

Tags: jquery, load

I have this code:

```
$("a.ajax").on('click', function() {
    ajax_link();
});

function ajax_link() {
   $('#ajax_load').remove(); // Remove js
   $('#section').html('<?php echo $this->ajax_loading; ?>');
   setInterval( function() {
       $('#section').load($(this).attr('href')+'&ajax=true'); 
       return false;
   }, 1000);
}
```

But when I click the link it reloads the page instead of loading the content. Does anyone know why?

I added the rest of the code to make sure its not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the anchor, which is causing the page to reload. You can do it via the `preventDefault()` method available in the event argument.

```
$("a.ajax").on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
      ajax_link.call(this);
});
```

Another issue is that inside the setInterval callback `this` represents the window and not the anchor you clicked on, so cache the `this` context to a variable and use it.

```
function ajax_link(){
var self = this; //Cache it here
setInterval(function(){
    $('#section').load(self.href +'&ajax=true'); 
        return false; //You dont need this.
     },1000);
}
```

Or Just bind it:

```
$("a.ajax").on('click', ajax_link);


function ajax_link(e){
var self = this; //Cache it here
e.preventDefault();
setTimeout(function(){ //Use setTimeout
    $('#section').load(self.href +'&ajax=true'); 
        return false; //You dont need this.
     },1000);
}
```

Comment: This still isn't working. The `#section` just goes blank now.

Comment: Seems to still not load the page. Do you need more info from me? If so what? Thanks mate

Comment: @Jay It has to Unless you are accesing url from another domain. Network console is your friend. Check for any error there.

Comment: hehe Its working, thanks so much. But the setinterval is making the page load every secdon, best remove that lol. But how would I get my loading image to display for at least 1-2 seconds?

Comment: @Jay Use setTimeout instead of setInterval. See my answer update.

Answer (score 0):

Use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

> the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$("a.ajax").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ajax_link();
});
```

or you can modify your HTML

```
<a class="ajax" href="javascript:void(0)">Load ajax</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of jQuery, you may return false from your click event handler.  Returning false will preventDefault() and stopPropagation().  StackOverflow has a reference to this... [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)